# Pass gradle command line arguments to application.properties

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have a Spring Boot Gradle application and many MySQL servers and databases.
In different scenarios, I want to start the application with different databases or create them if they do not exist. I want to use this mechanism with command line arguments.
The URL for database is stored in application.properties file of Spring:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true`

I want to run gradle with command line arguments that will apply to the application.properties file so in my head will be something like this.

application.properties :
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${linkNewDB}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true`

And to run the program as :
`gradle bootRun -Pargs=--linkNewDB="someNewDB:3309"`

Does anybody know how can I achieve this mechanism? I tried different options but none of them worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the whole URL, like this:

```
gradle bootRun --args='--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://someNewDB:3309?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true'
```

reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application.passing-arguments